# If dentro do Loop não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop

Boa noite. Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function verificaOnOff(){

  for(var i in tbModulos){

    var mod = tbModulos[i];

    $.get('http://'+ mod.ip +'/rele', function(data) {
        if (data == '1') {
          $('#icone-'+i).removeClass('branco');
          $('#icone-'+i).addClass('amarelo');
          $('input[id="'+i+'"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
          $('#icone-'+i).removeClass('amarelo');
          $('#icone-'+i).addClass('branco');
          $('input[id="'+i+'"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Ela, quando chamada, verifica se um relê está ligado ou não, via GET (0 ou 1).
Se receber 1, altera alguns parâmetros de CSS, e vice versa.

O problema é que, só está alterando o último. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Coloque um `console.log(i, data)` dentro do `$.get` para ver se está retornando e qual é o retorno

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss:  1 1, repetido 2 vezes. Os dois relês estão ligados.

Comment: Está fazendo um get num loop for.. só vai retornar o último porque é totalmente assíncrono.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso possivelmente aconteceu porque a referência de `i` será a mesma para todas as requisições. Como são requisições assíncronas, o laço terminará rapidamente, chegando ao valor máximo de `i`, que neste caso deve ser 1, antes que as requisições sejam completadas; assim, quando forem completadas, a função *callback* será chamada, todas com o valor de `i` igual a 1. Para contornar isso, você terá que criar referências distintas ao valor de `i` para cada requisição. A forma mais fácil de fazer isso é importá-lo para um escopo único de cada requisição, dentro de uma função:

```
function rele(modulo, i) {
    return $.get('http://'+ modulo.ip +'/rele', function(data) {
        const icone = $('#icone-'+i)
        const isOn = (data == '1')

        icone.removeClass(isOn ? 'branco' : 'amarelo');
        icone.addClass(isOn ? 'amarelo' : 'branco')
        $('input[id="'+i+'"]').prop('checked', isOn);
    })
}

function verificaOnOff(modulos){
    $.each(modulos, (i, modulo) => rele(modulo, i));
}
```

Assim, o valor de `i` de cada requisição estará limitado pelo escopo da função `rele`, único para cada uma. Além disso, algumas outras melhorias foram feitas no código.

---

Ao invés de ficar adicionando e removendo classes, por quê não utiliza um *data-attribute*? Com CSS mesmo você consegue personalizar os elementos de acordo com o valor do atributo. Veja um exemplo:

```js
$('[data-status]').on('click', function (event) {
  const newStatus = ($(this).attr('data-status') == '0') ? '1' : '0'
  $(this).attr('data-status', newStatus)
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li[data-status='0'] {
  color: lightgray;
}

li[data-status='1'] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-status='0'>Item 1</li>
  <li data-status='0'>Item 2</li>
  <li data-status='0'>Item 3</li>
  <li data-status='0'>Item 4</li>
  <li data-status='0'>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Assim, seu código ficaria algo como:

```
function rele(modulo, i) {
    return $.get('http://'+ modulo.ip +'/rele', function(data) {
        $('#icone-'+i).attr('data-status', data)
        $('input[id="'+i+'"]').prop('checked', data == '1');
    })
}
```

O que simplifica um pouco.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e explicação!

Comment: Humm, entendi. Não conhecia isso, irei usar. Obrigado mais uma vez Anderson!